Encountering "DocuSign_eSign::ApiError (Bad Request)" when attempting to obtain JWT bearer token
I'm currently integrating DocuSign into my Rails application, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to obtain a JWT bearer token for authentication. Whenever I make a request to obtain the token, I receive the following error:
DocuSign_eSign::ApiError (Bad Request):

This error occurs within the get_jwt_bearer_token method of my DocusignService. Here's the relevant code snippet:
def get_jwt_bearer_token
  api_client.set_base_path(@base_path)
  private_key_filename = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'docusign_private_key.txt')
  expires_in_seconds = 3600 # Adjust as needed
  scopes = ["signature", "impersonation"]

  api_client.request_jwt_user_token(@integration_key, @user_id, private_key_filename, expires_in_seconds, $SCOPES.join('+'))
end

I've cross-checked my environment variables and I confirm that the environment variables DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY, DOCUSIGN_USER_ID, and DOCUSIGN_ENDPOINT are correctly set. Additionally, I've verified that the private key file exists at the specified path.
I've also included the relevant configuration from my .env file
DOCUSIGN_ENDPOINT=https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
BASE_URL=localhost:3000 DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID=239XX015
DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY=9b53690f-1012-4XXf-a91b-c82635895b09
DOCUSIGN_USER_ID=95b81f2e-b0d6-4XXc-b429-eb40daXXb130
DOCUSIGN_AUTH_SERVER=account-d.docusign.com

Could anyone help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how I can resolve it?

Have you granted consent to your application? Consent must be granted once per authenticating user.
The scopes parameter also should be space delimited (looks like you're doing it as a +)
Also would be good to verify that that api_client.set_base_path(@base_path) is actually setting the base_path to "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth
If none of these work, open a support case with Docusign Developer Support.
